# Laravel whereRelation returning unexpected result

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 tables Artists and Artworks. The structure of which are:

### Artists

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe Blogg | 22 |
| 2 | Bob Duff | 34 |
| 3 | Mark Smith | 25 |

### Artworks

| id | title | sold | price | artist_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | flowers | 1 | 80.00 | 1 |
| 2 | plants | 1 | 50.00 | 2 |
| 3 | boxes | 0 | 100.00 | 2 |
| 3 | threads | 0 | 110.00 | 3 |

In the Artist Model I have a relation to artworks

```
public function artworks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Artwork::class);
}
```

In the Artwork Model I have the relation to artists

```
public function artist()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Artist::class);
}
```

I want to return all the artists with that have sold an artwork (sold is 1) and the name of the ans price of the sold artwork. The eloquent query I am using is:

```
 $artists = Artist::with('artworks')->whereRelation('artworks','sold','=',1)->get();
```

This does select all the Artists with sold artwork. However, if the artist has both a sold artwork and an unsold artwork it returns both. so the query would return:

| id | Names | title | sold | price | artist_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe Blogg | flowers | 1 | 80.00 | 1 |
| 2 | Bob Duff | plants | 1 | 50.00 | 2 |
| 3 | Bob Duff | boxes | 0 | 100.00 | 2 |

When the artwork with the title Boxes has not been sold, so should not be in the results

How do I get it so that I only return sold artworks?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cody Brew

Almost the right answer - but I am now getting all Artists whether they've sold an Artwork or not. Although the subquery now only selects sold Artwork.

I have added back the whereRelation to your answer and it now apperas to work

```
$artists = Artist::with(['artworks' => function($query) {$query->where('sold', 1);}])->whereRelation('artworks','sold','=',1)->get();
```